# Cut String by maxLines parameter, and by number of characters

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a class with a method that takes a summary string and breaks it down into a maximum number of lines (maxLines Parameter) and maximum number of characters per line (width parameter). All lines except the first line should be indented (they should start with a space character), but the second character in an indented line should not be another space (so that second space must not be included). The program should still work if you change the maxLine parameter r width.

Also, the code should check whether some special characters are in the String, like:

```
 \' , \" , \\ , \t , \b , \r , \f , \n
```

How can I inspect is many spaces in String like below? If there are many spaces in the String, I want to trim them, but I don't know how to. (These underscores represent spaces.)

```
"9:00 John_____________________________Doe until 10 30 at Office"

9:00 Jo
_hn____
_______
_____Do
```

With my code, I get this result:

```
 9:00 Jo
 _hn Doe
 _until 1
 _0 30 at
```

But I want THIS this output:

```
9:00 Jo
_hn Doe
_until_
_10 30_
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "9:00 John Doe until 10 30 at Office";
    int width = 7;
    int maxLine = 4;
    List<String> lisT = new LinkedList<>(getParts(str, width, maxLine));
    for (String part : lisT) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
}

public static List<String> getParts(String str, int width, int maxLine) {
    List<String> parts = new LinkedList<>();
    int count = 0;
    int len = str.length();
    String indent = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += width) {
        parts.add(indent + str.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + width)).trim());
        count++;
        indent = " ";
        if (count == maxLine)
            break;
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Comment: "How to inspect is some special characters in String;
How to inspect is many spaces in String like this: 9:00 John Doe until 10 30 at Office" are you asking how to count the special characters and the spaces in a String? What are you asking? Also - are those underscores supposed to be spaces, or underscores?

Comment: These underscores represent spaces. \'   , \"  , \\   , \t    , \b    , \r    , \f    , \n

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you edit your post to include that information so everyone can see it more easily? And again - what exactly are you trying to ask? It was very unclear to me from your description.

Comment: So its few questions in one, 1. i want to get these specific result, All lines except the first line should start with space. 2. check is some special characters in String i mention above. 3. if many spaces in String and i want to trim but i don't know how. 4. Program should work if change maxLine parameter r width.

Comment: your input string in your main is not the example given in the beginning...

Comment: Did either of the answers solve your problem? If so, please accept the best answer so that others can find it more easily if they have the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your rows might be too long because your `width = 7` includes the indent space, so your rows have a width of 8 instead of 7. I would try replacing `for (int i = 0; i < len; i += width) {...` with `for (int i = 1; i < len; i += width - 1) {...` and add a special statement right before the for loop for the 0th row, since you do not want to indent the 0th row. Something like this:

```
parts.add(str.substring(0, Math.min(len, i + width)).trim());
    for(...){...}
```

Let me know whether that seems to be the problem. If not, I can take another look. To answer your other questions:

To remove more than one space in the middle of a string, use this to replace all whitespace with exactly one space:

```
String result = replaceAll("\\s","");
```

You can remove the special characters with a regex like this:

```
String result = str.replaceAll("[\'\"\\\t\b\r\f\n]","");
```

Comment: Keara thank you very much, i forgot to answer you after your answer u help me a lot to solve my problem. Now everything works find;

Comment: Great! I'm glad your code works now. If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting it so other people can find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what you want? I really hope you don't have to implement this in something because I had to mangle this to make it work.  Hopefully this is homework

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "9:00 John Doe until 10 30 at Office";
    int width = 7;
    int maxLine = 4;
    List<String> lisT = new LinkedList<>(getParts(str, width, maxLine));
    for (String part : lisT) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
}

public static List<String> getParts(String str, int width, int maxLine){
    List<String> parts = new LinkedList<>();
    int endedAt = 0;
    boolean firstLine = true;
    boolean secondLine = true;
    String indent = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLine; i++) {
        if(endedAt<=str.length()) {
            String holder;
            if(firstLine) {
                holder = str.substring(endedAt, endedAt + width);
                firstLine = false;
            }
            else {
                if(secondLine){
                    width = width -1;
                    secondLine = false;
                }
                holder = indent + str.substring(endedAt, endedAt + width).trim();
            }
            parts.add(holder);
            endedAt = endedAt + width;
        }
    }
    return parts;
}
```

The output is

```
9:00 Jo
 hn Doe
 until
 10 30
```